# Find $k= constant$ so that $disc= 0$

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Find $k= constant$ so that $\lceil$ *https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant%5By%5E6%2By%5E2z%5E6%2Bz%5E2-y%5E2z%5E2(1%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2)-k(1%2Bz%5E2)z%5E2(y%2Bz)(y-z)(z-1)(z%2B1)%5D,z%5D* $\rfloor$
$$disc\!\left [\!disc[\!z^{2}(\!z^{2}- 1\!)^{2}(\!z^{2}+       1\!)+ (\!y^{2}- z^{2}\!)( \!y^{4}+ z^{6}- z^{4}- z^{2}\!)- k(\!z^{4}- 1\!)z^{2}( \!y^{2}- z^{2}\!)\!,\!y\!]\!,\!z\!\right ]\!=\!0$$

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: This site is about using *Mathematica*.  Questions about W|A are [off topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My view is it would have made for a reasonable question had there been copy-and-pasteable input provided. As for W|A query length limitations, might want to try it on the Wolfram Cloud instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your nested discriminants are zero for any real `k`.

```
Discriminant[
  z^2 (z^2 - 1)^2 (z^2 + 1) + (y^2 - z^2) (y^4 + z^6 - z^4 - z^2) - 
    k (z^4 - 1) z^2 (y^2 - z^2), y], z]
```

> `0`

This is correct because

```
zpoly = 
  Discriminant[
    z^2 (z^2 - 1)^2 (z^2 + 1) + (y^2 - z^2) (y^4 + z^6 - z^4 - z^2) - 
      k (z^4 - 1) z^2 (y^2 - z^2), y]
```

gives

[image: zpoly]

As you see `zpoly` has a multiple root at zero, so its discriminant must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

There are line length limits in WolframAlpha and I think that may be some of the reason you were not able to get a solution in a single step from WolframAlpha. So we use a trick that sometimes works to do somewhat more complicated calculations within WolframAlpha.

I did your inner discriminant as a separate WolframAlpha calculation

```
Discriminant[y^6+y^2z^6+z^2-y^2z^2(1+y^2+z^2)-k(1+z^2)z^2(y+z)(y-z)(z-1)(z+1),y]
```

and scraped the result

```
-64 z^8 (z^2 - 1)^4 ((z^2 - 1) z^4 k(z^2 + 1) + z^2) (4 z^2 k(z^2 + 1) (-k(z^2 + 1)*
((z^2 - 1) k(z^2 + 1) - 3 z^4 + z^2 + 3) - 3 z^6 + 8 z^4 + 5 z^2 - 6) + (z^2 + 1)*
(4 z^8 - 9 z^6 - 3 z^4 + 5 z^2 + 27))^2
```

and then tried to rearrange and simplify that and eliminate as many spaces as I could, without confusing WolframAlpha, to get the shortest possible expression to paste into this second separate WolframAlpha calculation of the outer overall discriminant.

```
Discriminant[-64*z^8*(z^2-1)^4*(1+z^2)^2*(27+(5+4*k*((k-3)*k-6))*z^2+(4*k*(5+
(k-4)*k)-3)*z^4+(-9-4*(k-4)*k*(2+k))*z^6-4*(k-1)^3*z^8)^2*(z^2*k*z^4+k*z^8),z]
```

or you can reach that via this

```
[WolframAlphalink][1]
```

And the result of that is

```
0
```

So I think the result is zero for all values of k.

Please check all this very carefully to make certain there are no mistakes.

Comment: $\text{k}= 1$ is true but I don$'$t think the result is for all values of $\text{k}$ $.$ The square can be equal to $0$ not $> 0$ $.$